# I found objects in database i don't created, when try to delete them get this error Field 'id' expected a number but got 'None'

Tags: mongodb, django-models

#### UPDATE

I made a room_slug as the primary key, and the problem is solved. but now the problem is in the chat app. when make a chat object and choose a room for it get this error:

> raise self.model.DoesNotExist( chat.models.Room.DoesNotExist: Room
> matching query does not exist.

---

I have these models in the chat app.

```
class Room(models.Model):
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    room_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50,
                                 unique=True)
    
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'chat'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.room_name
    
     
class Chat(models.Model): 
    sender    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    receiver  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    message   = models.TextField()
    image     = models.FileField(upload_to='chat_images', 
                                  blank=True, 
                                  null=True,
                                  validators=[validate_image_format,
                                              validate_image_size])
    chat_room   = models.ForeignKey("Room",
                                  related_name='chats', 
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE)   

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'chat'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Chat {self.chat_room}"
```

when run makemigartions and migrate, I found ojects without id is created and can't delete them.
I use mongo_db and I am created a routers.py to handel chat app models

```
class Chatrouter:
    """
    a router that sends queries for the chat model to the 'mongo_db' database
    and queries for other models to the 'default' database.
    """

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        return the database alias for reading operations.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'chat' :
            return 'mongo_db'
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        return the database alias for writing operations.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'chat':
            return 'mongo_db'
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        return true if a relation between obj1 and obj2 is allowed.
        """
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'chat' and obj2._meta.app_label == 'chat':
            return True
        elif obj1._meta.app_label == 'chat' or obj2._meta.app_label == 'chat':
            return False  # relations between chat models and other models are not allowed
        return None  # use the default behavior for other models

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        return true if migrations are allowed on the given database.
        """
        if app_label == 'chat':
            return db == 'mongo_db'  # migrations for chat models should only run on the 'mongo_db' database
        return None  # use the default behavior for other models
```

I delete the objects using ORM.

```
>>> for i in  Room.objects.all():
...     print(i.id)
...
None
>>> for i in  Room.objects.all():
...     if i.id == None:
...             i.delete()
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\C.M\Downloads\chat-app\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1111, in delete
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Room object can't be deleted because its id attribute is set to None.
```

How delete these objects from the database and why these objects are created?
also when I try to add a new record I get this error

> raise db_exe from e
> django.db.utils.DatabaseError

Comment: This question needs more focus. Is it asking 1) how to delete documents in MongoDB? 2) Why those entries are being created? 3) What is causing that database error? 4) Something else entirely? Whichever it is we need more information to assist anyway. Please update your question to narrow the focus and provide more details about the specific issue the you are facing

Comment: I don't know why these objects are being created.
I updated the question and added how delete them.

Comment: I am trying to make a chat app using websocket I have an accounts app that has a custom user model stored in SQLite, and the chat app has Room and Chat models stored in mongo_db. also in chat app has a consumer and routing files.